# What do you call someone who gives little time to complete work?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What do you call someone who gives little time to complete work?  For example, a teacher who asks for a submission on a difficult project within just a few days.

Example sentence:

> That teacher is such a _____.

Comment: Perhaps a [**taskmaster**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/taskmaster) ~ A person who imposes a harsh or onerous workload on someone.

Comment: What is the meaning that you are trying to impart? Stupidity, cruelty, cluelessness?

Comment: Most terms for this are rather offensive -- idiot, bastard, slave-driver, etc.

Comment: **a swaggering, overbearing, tin-plated dictator with delusions of godhood** (Like Captain Kirk in Trouble With Tribbles)

Comment: Here, the teacher gives an unrealistic deadline. Is she/he unrealistic? Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That teacher is such a **tyrant**.

The *tyrant*, according to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tyrant), is:

> A person exercising power or control in a cruel, unreasonable, or arbitrary way

Which is obviously not exclusively about time, but it could involve erratic changes to planning.

Answer (score 0):

**disciplinarian**

> *n.* A person who believes in or practises firm discipline.

When used in the context of a teacher, it has strong connotations to things such as harsh deadlines.

> That teacher is such a **disciplinarian**.

Few other synonyms work as well as **martinet**

> *n.* A person who demands complete obedience; a strict disciplinarian.
>
> > That teacher is such a **martinet**.

*Both [[1]](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disciplinarian) [[2]](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/martinet) definitions from Lexico Oxford Dictionaries.*